# Ensure proper order of spring-integration events

Tags: tcp, spring-integration

We are using spring-integration for TCP communication, and see behaviour where a TcpConnectionCloseEvent is received just before a message on that connection.

This is a problem because we are using the TCP events to keep track of connections, etc. and it makes for much more complex scenarios when we need to accept messages on connections that we consider closed.

The same is the case the other way around - sometimes we receive a message for a connection that we do not yet know has been opened.

Is there any way to ensure the correct order of these events, even though they are asynchronous in nature?

(Thanks for the great answers here on stackoverflow, Gary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm...

On the server side, the open event is published by the thread that accepts the new connection rather than the connection itself. While we could possibly do something there, it still wouldn't be foolproof when using NIO because the threading model there is much more complex and there would be no way to guarantee the order even if the connection itself published the event.

To be honest, we didn't anticipate the events would be used in this way - the primary driver (for the open events) was to allow an application to detect a new connection without the client actually sending anything (just connecting) - allowing a server-side application to accept a new connection, get a handle to the connection id so it can send a welcome message.

One workaround might be to use an event inbound channel adapter and a `<delayer/>` to delay the event delivery to your application (in the case of the close).

I don't really have a good solution for the late delivery of the open event; perhaps just treat an inbound message for a "new" connection as an "open" event (e.g. publish your own open event when you detect this condition on the thread that's processing the message, and ignore the "real" event).

Comment: Ok, thanks. We are currently using it much as you describe. We will keep doing that then :)